# uint casting in Protocol Buffer

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

I defined a Color message in [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) as follows:

```
message Color {
    fixed32 rgb = 1;
}
```

I am defining Color in C# language as following:

```
byte red    = pixels[4 * index + 0];
byte green  = pixels[4 * index + 1];
byte blue   = pixels[4 * index + 2];
byte alpha  = pixels[4 * index + 3];
Color color = new Color
{
    Rgb = (uint)((red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue)
};
```

I am worried if the following operation is valid or not:

```
Rgb = (uint)((red << 16) | (green << 8) | blue)
```

Please note that, without `uint` cast, the program is throwing compilation errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's perfectly valid. What is happening here is that the shift operators (`<<` / `>>`) on `byte` return `int`. Because... reasons. Actually, *almost all* operators on `byte` return `int` - the "or" (`|`) of two `byte` values is *also* an `int`.

The compiler doesn't like *blindly* letting you cast an `int` to a `uint`, so it just wants you to acknowledge that you're doing this, which is what the `(uint)` that you've added does.

Since we know that you're only populating the first 24 bits, we know that the value is always positive, so it will *always* be a positive integer that can be safely cast as unsigned (`uint`).

If you were filling all 32 bits, there *is a chance* that the final value would be negative, but **by default** the C# compiler works in "unchecked" mode, so: it doesn't care. It will happily cast a negative `int` to a `uint`. `-8` becomes `4294967288`, for example. However, *as a command line option*, "checked" mode can be enabled - in which case you'll get an `OverflowException`. To avoid that, the `unchecked` modifier can be used to tell it to *explicitly* not care, for example:

```
int i = -8;
uint u = unchecked((uint)i);
```

or

```
unchecked
{
    int i = -8;
    uint u = (uint)i;
    // ...
}
```

However, this usage of `unchecked` is *almost never* needed. It is more common for people to add the occasional `checked` modifier in the places that they *do* care about overflows.

So to conclude: yes, what you have is fine.

Comment: Thank you very much. In other words, may I say that if I define color including alpha value too as `fixed32 rgba`, then I should better add following  `Rgba = unchecked((uint)(red << 24) | (green << 16) | (blue << 8) | (alpha))`. Isn't it?

Comment: @RaviJoshi unless you're going out of your way to enable "checked mode", then it won't matter; if you want the code to work identically *regardless* of whether someone enables "checked mode" in the build, then sure

Comment: I see. I am a little bit confused here. In the example above, you mentioned that `unchecked` and also explained that it matters in case of negative numbers. However, alpha is transparency and it can never be negative. We know in advance about it. Hence do I really need to use `unchecked'?

Comment: @Ravi in twos-complement binary arithmetic, if the most significant bit is 1, then the value is negative. So if the alpha is 128 or above, and you then left-shift it 24 places, then your 32-bit integer has a 1 in the most significant bit, and is negative something. Note: if you aren't filling the 4th byte, you don't need to worry about it at all: you can't get a negative int32 if you're only combining r, g and b into the lower 24 bits - so the unchecked isn't needed until you add "alpha"

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you very much.